# get values of a row of asp.net gridview onclick and send email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

as u can see from below aspx code i need values of row of the gridview

1)My gridview last column contains dropdownlist.it contains two values (qualified/disqualifed).on selecting qualified or disqaulified i need to get all the values of the row of gridview....

2)after getting all the values i need to send those values to email...the email should be send to the particular email id of email column,

For eg-if i select 1st row from gridview.and in that 1st row if i select ist  dropdownlist(either qualified/disqualified).after selecting qualified/disqualified from dropdownlist i need to get all the values of the first row..and i need to send all the values of the first row  of gridviews through email to the emai id of first row.....

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
       BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px"
       CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black" Height="122px"
       Width="495px" onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
       <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Application No" DataField="appno" />
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="appname" />
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Company Name" DataField="cname" />
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Post Name" DataField="pname" />
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" DataField="email" />
           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Mobile No" DataField="mobile" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="mksobtain" HeaderText="Marks Obtain" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="mkstot" HeaderText="Total Marks" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="hrname" HeaderText="HR Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="hrno" HeaderText="HR No" />
           <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qualification Process">
               <EditItemTemplate>
                   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                   <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
              AutoPostBack="True" >
                   </asp:DropDownList>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
   </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the email, you need to either use the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of the drop down list or add a `Send Email` button to the grid view markup and handle the click event for that button or create a `CommandName` attribute. This choice determines how you will get the row you want to get the values from.

Because you are using `BoundField`s in your grid view markup, you will need to reference the values of the row via the `Cells` collection of the row, like this:

```
// Assuming you have the row object, either from e.Row or 
// finding the parent or grandparent of the click event sender
GridViewRow theGridViewRow;

// Get the application number value
string theApplicationNumber = theGridViewRow.Cells[0].Text;

// Do similar logic for each field you want the value of here
```

Instead of depending upon the index value of the `Cells` collection, I recommend you use `TemplateField`s in your grid view markup, like this:

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application No">
        <asp:Label id="LabelApplicationNumber" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('appno') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <asp:Label id="LabelApplicationName" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('appname') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Name">
        <asp:Label id="LabelCompanyName" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('cname') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Name">
        <asp:Label id="LabelPostName" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('pname') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
        <asp:Label id="LabelEmail" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('email') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Mobile No">
        <asp:Label id="LabelMobileNumber" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('mobile') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marks Obtain">
        <asp:Label id="LabelMarksObtain" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('mksobtain') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Marks">
        <asp:Label id="LabelTotalMarks" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('mkstot') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HR Name">
        <asp:Label id="LabelHRName" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('hrname') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HR No">
        <asp:Label id="LabelHRNumber" runat="server" 
                   Text="<%# Eval('hrno') %>" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Qualification Process">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
                              AutoPostBack="True" >
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Now in your code-behind, you can use the `FindControl()` method to get the values from the row instead of using the `Cells[i]` notation, like this:

```
// Assuming you have the row object, either from e.Row or 
// finding the parent or grandparent of the click event sender
GridViewRow theGridViewRow;

// Find the application number label control in the row
var theApplicationNumberLabel = theGridViewRow.FindControl("LabelApplicationNumber") as Label;

// Make sure we found the label before we try to use it
if(theApplicationNumberLabel != null)
{
    // Get the value
    string theApplicationNumber = theApplicationNumberLabel.Text;
}

// Do similar logic for each control in the row you want the value of here
```